# How to best include an introductory phrase before getting to the point?

Tags: grammar, formality, internet

This question may seem too large in scope from the title, but here's the preface to the answer I seek.

I need to inform my hiring manager (HM) that I have served my last day with my current organization yesterday (which is no more "current" now that I've quit). I need to send a casual message to the manager, but I am still struggling with the way to phrase this without sounding too casual or unintentionally formal. Conveying this information is important as I was unsure of how long my notice period would be and so was the HM.

I am thinking of drafting the message in this manner:

> Hi, just wanted to keep you apprised of my developments..I have served my last day, yesterday, with my current organization. Awaiting to receive an approved commencement date email from NEW EMPLOYER. Can't wait to join your team.

I'd appreciate if someone can better phrase this context as well as please suggest whether usage of ellipsis in sms-es is fine. Is the usage of "just wanted to keep you informed about my developments" as a starting point for the rest of the context fine?

Comment: You've split an infinitive in your question title!! :-o Sorry - there's always one, isn't there.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for pointing that out. Not a forbidden usage though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to message as in text message (SMS)? You should stress you are ready to start your new job and that the only thing pending is that they confirm your commencement date. I wouldn't use any intro, any ellipsis dots and definitely not all caps.

Here are two suggestions.

> Hi, just to let you know yesterday was my last notice day with my
> previous employer. I'm ready to start in my new role, only waiting for
> your confirmation email with a starting date. Looking forward to joining
> the team!

A bit more formal:

> Dear X,
>
> This is to inform you yesterday was my last notice/working day with my
> previous employer and that I'm ready to start in my new role. I'm only
> waiting for an email from you confirming my commencement date.
>
> Please keep me posted with any update and let me know if I can prepare any
> paperwork in the meantime. Looking forward to joining the team!
>
> Regards,
>
> X

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I went with the first alternative.